# Total explained variance based on three dependent correlation coefficients

Tags: statistics, dependencies, correlation

Is there any way to compute the total explained variance of a variable x explained by two dependent variables y and z when only the three correlation coefficients are known?

Let's say the following correlations are available (but not the raw data):

xy = 0.71

xz = 0.25

yz = 0.33

Then what is the total explained variance of x?

Several of my approaches via (semi-)partial correlations resulted in values > 1.
Does anyone know a formula for this case?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the value you are looking for is the R<sup>2</sup> if x was predicted by y and z, i.e. the total variance explained in x by y and z.
Here is a post that explains this, from which I got the formula: [Can you calculate R<sup>2</sup>
from correlation coefficients in multiple linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/364630/396429)

In case you are familiar with R, I wrote out some code to validate it for your specific example:

```
# Correlations
xy <- 0.71
xz <- 0.25
yz <- 0.33

# Correlation of each predictor with dependent variable
r_pred_DV <- matrix(c(xy, xz), ncol = 1)
# Correlation between predictors
r_pred_pred <- matrix(c(1, yz, yz, 1), ncol = 2)

R_sq <- t(r_pred_DV) %*% solve(r_pred_pred) %*% r_pred_DV

# Same thing with example data:
library(faux)                        # for data simulation
set.seed(1234)
n <- 50           
y <- rnorm(n)
z <- rnorm_pre(y, r = yz, empirical = TRUE)
x <- rnorm_pre(data.frame(y, z), r = c(xy, xz), empirical = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(y, z, x)
cor(data)                            # correlation matrix is the same 

model <- lm(x ~ y + z, data = data)
summary(model)$r.squared             # same as with formula
```